# Reset Scroll View when returning from View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

UIScrolView Noob Here..

I currently have two view controllers.

First view controller contains a Long Image View embedded in a UI View embedded in a scroll View.

Image view has a button at the top and at the bottom. Both buttons lead to the next view.

Scroll is working as i can scroll to the bottom of the image and back to the top.

when top button is clicked i am taken to next view...then a button from there can return to the first view and i can continue scrolling down and back up.

Problem occurs when bottom button is clicked and i then return from the next view.

I cannot scroll back upwards and can only see the bottom part of the image.

by looking online ive found two potential solutions, of which neither work for me:

sol1:
[self.scrollViewFront scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];

sol2:
[scrollViewFront setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];

my scroll view contentSize is set as follows:

self.scrollViewFront.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 775);

There must be a way i can return back to the top half of the image instead of being stuck towards the bottom.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is not with the scrollView, but with the transition to or from the second next view.  Try swapping the actions associated with the buttons.  Does transitioning to the view originally associated with the top button work if associated with the bottom instead?

Comment: Both buttons have the same push action as the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. Both use the same prepareForSegue as well, so im not sure swapping them will make a difference...

Comment: when the bottom button is clicked, next view is shown, when i return i cant scroll up, but i can scroll down to white empty space...hope this helps. thanks

Comment: Can you post the full code for both views?  Given the behavior you describe I would expect the issue to be easy to spot.  The best way to post your code is by editing your original question and appending it there.